# [MapBox]NavigationMapRoute not resolved

Tags: android, navigation, mapbox

```
    repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }

    dependencies {
    //Mapbox
    compile('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.1.3@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    //Navigation
    compile 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.5.0'

    compile 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.6.0-SNAPSHOT'

    //Location layer
    compile 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-locationlayer:0.1.0'

    //Geolocation
    compile 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-ui:2.1.3'


    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'


    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
```

I was developing a MapBox Navigation Android App. However, Android Studio cannot resolved the symbol when I trying to import the package

**import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.route.NavigationMapRoute;**

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio 3.0.1
You Can Add This Lib. Like that

**See on Build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.demosmartstop"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"

        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    //TODO OTHEWR ACTIVITYS
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'

    compile 'com.github.whinc:ratingbar:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'

    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    //TODO RECYCLE VIEW
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'

    //TODO picaso for download image into device
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    //TODO PopUu Window ToolPit
    compile 'com.fenchtose:tooltip:0.1.5'

    //Retrofit
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'

    //TODO MAPBOX LIB

    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.9.0'
    implementation('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.9.0') {
        transitive = true
    }

    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.3.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    implementation('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.3.2@aar') {
        transitive = true

    }

    //TODO MAultidex LIB
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'

}
```

And Other One Is Like That

Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        classpath 'org.ajoberstar:gradle-git:1.7.0' // or higher
        classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.2.0'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        //TODO Toltip Window
        maven {  url  "http://dl.bintray.com/jayrambhia/maven"   }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```